# How can I send my emails in Thunderbird to Gmail?

Tags: gmail, thunderbird

I had, a long time ago, a non-free email account. Once I opened a Gmail account I forgot about it, but I still have all the emails stored (in Thunderbird format).

I would like to be able to join them with my current Gmail account, as it is always difficult to search for old emails. The ideal will be keeping the fields like `To`, `Cc`, etc, but just forwarding everything to Gmail could be enough.

I'm talking of about 700Mb of information.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could add your Gmail account as a new IMAP account to Thunderbird. From there you can just drag them from your old account folder to the Gmail/[All Mail] folder.

See http://email.about.com/od/gmailtips/qt/How_to_Import_Mail_from_Mozilla_Thunderbird_in_Gmail.htm for steps.

Comment: I have done this with Fastmail (another IMAP provider), and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your mails stored as mbox files, you can use the [gmail uploader](http://www.gmailuploader.com/) web app.